# Ignore " when creating string in vb.net?

Tags: vb.net

I want to create a string with " in it, but they are used in defining them. So, trying to create a string with " will just end the string.

Is there a way around this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Dim Something As String

Something = "abc""def"
' Something contains abc"def
```

You have to escape a quote with another quote.

If you need a quote at either end of a string, use 3 quotes together:

```
Something = """abc"""
' Something contains "abc"
```